# driver.close does not work when a javascript alert is in view

Tags: java, selenium

The following code gets executed properly if i comment out the driver.close() part. However if i run the program using it, the program fails and gives an error.

Also the same program does not work in Chrome browser and works only in Firefox. Kindly suggest!

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class JavaAlerts 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
System.setProperty( "webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptalert.php");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Confirmation Alert']")).click();
driver.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Here is the error message.                                                                                 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Unexpected modal dialog (text: Are you sure you want to give us the deed to your house?): Are you sure you want to give us the deed to your house?
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '

Comment: Once you've switched to alert You don't need to switch it again.Assign it to Alert Object and then accept it –and add it to the question and remove it as an answer and chek my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to switchTo() alert and close the alert first and close driver

Comment: so basically the thing is you can't close a driver till the alert is there? also can you help with the other part?

Comment: For chrome i get the following exception: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.130)

Comment: i tried what you said and even after closing the alert, the driver.close() did not get executed!

Answer (score 0):

You have to [switchToAlert](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#alert()) and then [Accept](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html#accept()) it

```
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptalert.php");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Confirmation Alert']")).click();
    Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
    System.out.println(alert.getText());
    alert.accept();
    driver.quit();
```

[From Your Code in Comment]
Once you've switched to alert You don't need to switch to Alert again as the driver will be at the alert at present.Assign it to Alert Object and then accept it or print it or do what ever you want

Comment: Once you've switched to alert You don't need to switch it again.Assign it to Alert Object and then accept it

Comment: sorry i answered it out, since code was not clear in my comment

Comment: @icantcode Check the updated answer. Just edit your post and add it over there and delete it

Comment: can you help me with Alert alert thing. What's Alert here and then whats alert. just a basic context

Comment: @icantcode `Alert` is an interface for these kind of Popups written in selenium.Same as `WebDriver` is for Browser, `Alert` is for these javascript alerts

Comment: @icantcode you can read about in the first [link](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#alert()) in the answer

Comment: oh ok. so just one basic java question: in webdriver we use- WebDriver driver= new WebDriver(); and her we say Alert alert= driver.switchto().alert. what's the difference here then. Also in the link you gave i have one doubt: Alert is an interface and accept, dismiss are its methods. then what is alert() method for and it belongs which class/interface?

Comment: .alert() is used Get a handle to the open alert, prompt or confirmation which returns Alert Object

Comment: why did not we write it like this then? Alert alert= new Alert(); ? we did not create an object in that case?

Comment: Alert is an interface and you can instantiate an interface..You have to read about Interface Inheritance and OOPs concept then only you can get a glimpse of it

Comment: Alert what you are getting is RemoteAlert You can see that over [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.java)

Comment: please help me with this. We have an interface Alert where accept() and dismiss are it's methods(). What does this means Alert alert=driver.switchto().alert. We can not instantiate an interface like this for sure Interface interface= new Interface();, then what were you talking about exactly?

Comment: `driver.switchto().alert()` will return `RemoteAlert` with implements Alert interface [`private class RemoteAlert implements Alert`] you can see that in the link in my Prevoius Comment. and you can instantiate interface .Refer [this](http://javabykg.blogspot.in/)

Comment: so basically driver.switchto().alert() is returning an object which is of class remotealert which implements alert interface? @madhan

Comment: if yes  my final questions is can we write this way for classes as well or only for interfaces. Class class= say.something(); and Interface interface=say.sometouhing(). Is there a link that you can point me to which says reference variables of class can be created with "new operator" only and interface without it?

Comment: @icantcode yes. And I guess that code is bit hard for you to decode.Anyhow You can code if you read the basics.And accept the answer if it help solve your problem[I guess so]

Comment: just explain my final question as well with proper links and some insight into specifically the instantiation part and difference for a class and interface here? @madhan

Comment: I guess this Link [What is Interface](http://javabykg.blogspot.in/) is enough and you can also go through [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm)

Comment: the link u gave says   an interface is different from a class in several ways, including:
 
    You cannot instantiate an interface. and u said u can instantiate. please explain here itself if possible. would be quite helpful in moving on with basic doubt cleared here

Comment: To be simple Animal is interface and Dog is a class which implements Animal.Animal can eat.But how will be answered by Dog only..

Comment: you are not getting my query. just tell me this. why did not we use the new keyword for Alert alertac= new xyz();. just tell me about this new keyword here for interface. rest u have cleared all my queries

Comment: Alert alert=new Alert() wont work;Alert alert=new RemoteAlert() will work.Because objects can only be created for classes and not for interfaces.Idk how to explain.You can read more about in Google.Create a simple interface and class and try to do You'll learn yourself

Comment: Sorry I'm not a native English speaker. What I wanted to say might be interpreted differently by you and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I use this together with JUnit to not get the error message when closing:

```
  @After
  public void quitDriver() throws Exception {


        // driver.quit();

      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM firefox.exe");
      Thread.sleep(3000);
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM plugin-container.exe");
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM WerFault.exe");

  }
```

I also see that you both are loading the Crome properties and starting Firefox.
You should do one of them (not a pretty example):

```
System.setProperty( "webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
```

To

```
//System.setProperty( "webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
//WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
```

Or

```
System.setProperty( "webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
//WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
```